# Encadenar promesas en orden de entrada

Tags: nodejs, express, promesas, backend

Tengo la siguiente funcion getInfo, accede a un objeto que internamente tiene una propiedad results que a su vez es un array de objetos con una propiedad url, necesito resolver la url interna pero cuando recorre el array results obtengo el resultado de la promesa interna en desorden me trae los datos en desorden, requiero que conforme avanza en el array results me traiga los resultados de la correspondiente URL, confirme con un console.log(url) que la url esta llegando en orden

```
const getInfo = async () => {
  let pokemones = [];
  const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon');
  const data = await response.json();
  data.results.forEach((poke) => {
    pokemones.push(poke)
  });
  pokemones.forEach( async ({url}) => {
    console.log(url)
    await fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(resp => {
      console.log(resp.name)
    })
  }, 0)
}
```

Comment: Hay 2 opciones... la primera opcion es ejecutar la primera promesa y esperar resultado, luego ejecutar la segunda promesa y esperara el resultado, y asi sucesivamente... la otra es crear todos los fetch que necesites y mandarlos a ejecutar todos al tiempo, una vez todos terminen, revisar los resultados de todos. Cual te funcionaría?

Comment: Segun la logica funcionaria la primera opcion, solo que lo he estado intentando, pero sigue retornandome la segunda promesa, la interna, en desorden, pense usar el promiseAll pero realmente no me esta funcionando la segunda promesa

Comment: Para que la primera funcione, no uses un `.forEach`, usa un simple `for(let pokemon of pokemones){ await fetch(url)... }`, así esperas que ese fetch retorne algo, antes de continuar con el ciclo... el `forEach` no permite eso por eso el await dentro del forEach no funciona

Comment: Sorprendente, funciono a la perfección